# why does background-color fill only part of div?

Tags: html, css, background-color

I have two headers enclosed inside one div. The div background color fills the first header but not the second. Why is this? I would assume that putting two divs inside one div would cause them to inherit the background color. I have done this before without problems. Thank you.

```
<div id="contain">


<header id="head_1">
    <img src="images/Logos/Actlogo.png"/>
   <p> P.O. Box 4524 </br>
       Wattville </br>
       </br>
       (203) 444 - 4444 </br>
        www.Acts4Peace.com
   <p>
</header>


<!-- menu and statement -->
<header id="head_2">
   <p>Keeping Families Warm in Winter</p>


    <ul>  <!-- main menu -->
        <li> <a href="#"> Furniture </a>
            <ul> <!-- submenu -->
            <li> <a href="#"> Couches </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Chairs </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Tables </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li> <a href="#"> Clothing </a>
            <ul> <!-- submenu -->
            <li> <a href="#"> Women </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Men </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Kids </a></li>
            </ul>
       </li>

        <li> <a href="#"> Kitchen </a> 
            <ul> <!-- submenu -->
            <li> <a href="#"> Utensils </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Blenders </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Baking </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>

</header>
```

```
 #contain {   /* main wrapper */
    width: 1200px;
    background-color: tan;
    margin: auto;
 }


 #head_1 p {     /* mailing address floated right */
   float: right;
   text-align: right;
   font-size: 11pt;
 }


 @font-face {
    font-family: cursive;
    src: url(C:/Windows/Fonts/Cursive standard.ttf);
 }


 #head_2 p {    /*second header paragraph, business mission*/
    float: right;
    font-family: "cursive standard";
    font-size: 26pt;
 }
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle? I tried your code and I don't see the issue you're having

Comment: What browser/version are you using?

Comment: Yes, demo needed, as your code doesn't show the problem. Remember that the `<header>` element has a *meaning*. Just use divs instead until you understand the purpose of `header`.

Comment: I'm using Brackets to edit instead of Notepad++. It updates on the fly; maybe that is why I'm not seeing the right colors. I will try in on Notepad and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the header tag twice, I would put the two elements in separate divs, withing one . Then change the background of either , or the two divs inside.

```html
<div id="contain">
  
<header>

    <div id="head_1">
      <img src="images/Logos/Actlogo.png"/>
         <p> P.O. Box 4524 </br>
            Wattville </br>
            </br>
            (203) 444 - 4444 </br>
            www.Acts4Peace.com
         <p>
    </div>


<!-- menu and statement -->
<nav>
    <p>Keeping Families Warm in Winter</p>


    <ul>  <!-- main menu -->
        <li> <a href="#"> Furniture </a>
            <ul> <!-- submenu -->
            <li> <a href="#"> Couches </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Chairs </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Tables </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li> <a href="#"> Clothing </a>
            <ul> <!-- submenu -->
            <li> <a href="#"> Women </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Men </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Kids </a></li>
            </ul>
       </li>

        <li> <a href="#"> Kitchen </a> 
            <ul> <!-- submenu -->
            <li> <a href="#"> Utensils </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Blenders </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Baking </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>

  </nav>

</header> 

</div>
```

```html
 #contain {   /* main wrapper */
    width: 1200px;
    background-color: tan;
    margin: auto;
 }


 #head_1 p {     /* mailing address floated right */
   float: right;
   text-align: right;
   font-size: 11pt;
 }


 @font-face {
    font-family: cursive;
    src: url(C:/Windows/Fonts/Cursive standard.ttf);
 }


nav p {    /*second header paragraph, business mission*/
    float: right;
    font-family: "cursive standard";
    font-size: 26pt;
 }

header {
    background-color:#;
}
```

Comment: I think I see the problem. The menu and "Keeping Families Warm in Winter" elements are both floated. Therefore, they are out of the flow and the div doesn't fill in their position with color since they're not "really there.

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't recreate your issue (perhaps the window in JSFiddle isn't big enough), from your comment to Adam Ciardelli it appears this is a float issue. You can set `overflow:hidden` on `.contain` or use a clearfix:

```
#contain {   /* main wrapper */
  width: 1200px;
  background-color: tan;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/q3kc8bhg/)